# building a menu list object recursively in javascript with a child key

Tags: javascript

I've been building upon a previous post

[building a menu list object recursively in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308903/building-a-menu-list-object-recursively-in-javascript)

I used that to learn more about arrays and objects in js and it output

```
{ 
    social: {
        swipes: {
            women: null
        }
    }
}
```

but now I want it in a way that's more practical that'd make it easier to traverse in a format like

```
{
    social: {
        children: {
            swipes: {
                children: {
                    women: null
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

with a children key.

how can I modify the code to do so?

```js
let input = ['/social/swipes/women', '/social/swipes/men', '/upgrade/premium'];

let output = input.reduce((o, e) => {
  let z = e.split("/").filter(d => d);
  
  z.reduce((k,v,i) => {

    if (z.length - 1 !== i) {
      if (k.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
        k[v] = k[v];
      } else {
        k[v] = { children: {}};
      }
    } else {
      k[v] = null;
    }

    return k[v]
  }, o)

  return o;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the code like below to achieve this

```js
let input = ['/social/swipes/women', '/social/swipes/men', '/upgrade/premium'];

let output = input.reduce((o, d) => {
  let keys = d.split('/').filter(d => d)
  
  keys.reduce((t, k, i) => {
    t[k] = (i != keys.length - 1)
              ? (t[k] || { children: {} })
              : null

    return t[k] && t[k].children
  }, o)
  
  return o
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = ['/social/swipes/women', '/social/swipes/men', '/upgrade/premium'];
let output = {};

input.forEach((x) => {
  var currentPath = output;
  var lastIndex = x.split('/').slice(1).length - 1;
  x.split('/').slice(1).forEach((y, index) => {
    currentPath.childern = currentPath.childern || {};
    currentPath.childern[y] = currentPath.childern[y] || {};
        
    if (lastIndex == index) {
      currentPath.childern[y] = null;
    }
    
    currentPath = currentPath.childern[y];
  });
});

output = output.childern;
console.log(output);
```